# Using JCROP and JQUERY to crop images using from jsp..url based image source/ dynamic images not working

Tags: java, jquery, image, jcrop

i have the following code that works perfectly fine to display an image in a Jsp so that i can crop it. The code uses a static image "testpic.jpg" which works perfectly well without issues. When i attempt to use a dynamic image generated from a servlet, JCROP seems to fail to initialize so i get the images, but i will not have the cropping functionality enabled. i use 
`<img src="displayImage?memberNumber=<%=memberNumber%>&amp;memberSuffix=<%=memberSuffix%>&amp" id="cropbox" />`
 to display the dynamic images. The displayImage servlet is shown below.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />

        <script language="Javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
                jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                    onChange: updateCoords,
                    onSelect: updateCoords
                });
      });


            function updateCoords(c)
            {
                $('#x').val(c.x);
                $('#y').val(c.y);
                $('#w').val(c.w);
                $('#h').val(c.h);
            }
            ;

            function checkCoords()
            {
                if (parseInt($('#w').val()))
                    return true;
                alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
                return false;
            }
            ;

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                width: 500px;
                clear: both;
            }
            .container input {
                width: 100%;
                clear: both;
            }
            #wrapper {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 400px;
            }
            #wrapper2 {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 200px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container" id="wrapper">

            <h1>Resize your picture</h1>

            <!-- This is the image we're attaching Jcrop to -->
            <img src="../testpic.jpg" id="cropbox" />

            <!-- This is the form that our event handler fills -->

            <form action="cropImage.jsp" method="get"
                  onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="l" />
                <input type="hidden" id="y" name="t" />
                <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                <input type="hidden"  id="f" name="f" value="jpg" />
                <input type="hidden"  id="i" name="i" 
                       value="pic.jpg"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

But when i substitute with a URL of a servlet that streams the image into the JSP, the image is shown BUT JCROP stops working, i cant crop the image. Any pointers where i am going wrong, or its simply because jcrop only works with static images? The code below uses a dynamic image but doesnt seem to work..

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />

        <script language="Javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
            jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                    onChange: updateCoords,
                    onSelect: updateCoords
                });
      });


            function updateCoords(c)
            {
                $('#x').val(c.x);
                $('#y').val(c.y);
                $('#w').val(c.w);
                $('#h').val(c.h);
            }
            ;

            function checkCoords()
            {
                if (parseInt($('#w').val()))
                    return true;
                alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
                return false;
            }
            ;

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                width: 500px;
                clear: both;
            }
            .container input {
                width: 100%;
                clear: both;
            }
            #wrapper {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 400px;
            }
            #wrapper2 {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 200px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
<%
String memberNumber = request.getAttribute("memberNumber").toString();
String memberSuffix = request.getAttribute("memberSuff`enter code here`ix").toString();
%>
    <body>

        <div class="container" id="wrapper">

            <h1>Resize your picture</h1>

            <!-- This is the image we're attaching Jcrop to -->
            <img src="displayImage?memberNumber=<%=memberNumber%>&amp;memberSuffix=<%=memberSuffix%>&amp" id="cropbox" />

            <!-- This is the form that our event handler fills -->

            <form action="cropImage.jsp" method="get"
                  onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="l" />
                <input type="hidden" id="y" name="t" />
                <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                <input type="hidden"  id="f" name="f" value="jpg" />
                <input type="hidden"  id="i" name="i" 
                       value="testpic.jpg"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the DisplayImage servlet....

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String memberNumber = request.getParameter("memberNumber");
    String memberSuffix = request.getParameter("memberSuffix");
    System.out.println(memberNumber + memberSuffix);
    try {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAExamplePU");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            String primarykey = memberNumber + memberSuffix;

            Photos photo = em.find(Photos.class, primarykey);
        if ((memberNumber != null)&&(photo!=null)) {

            byte[] image = photo.getPassportPhoto();
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.getOutputStream().write(image);
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();

            System.out.println("''''''''''''''''''''''> sending to display");
        }} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }          }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Comment: I suspect that have a timing issues.

It is likely that you are attempting to attach JCrop before your image is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorGowing for the so much needed response. That makes sense to me. I am still stuck. In your opinion what could be the best way to handle this?

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you were on the right track using jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event but we want to know when the image is loaded not the window. So try:

```
$("#cropbox").load(function(){
            $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                onChange: updateCoords,
                onSelect: updateCoords
            });
  });
```

so that you only attach jcrop once the image is loaded rather than once the window has loaded.